# Text in UserControl TextBox disappear after click on a button

Tags: c#, user-controls, postback, repeater

Good day,

I have a aspx page name MakeRedemption.aspx.

Inside this MakeRedemption.aspx, I have a UserControl page name SearchGift.ascx.

Inside SearchGift.ascx, I have a repeater. Inside this repeater, I have another UserControl page name InfoForm.ascx.

Which is means, SearchGift.ascx contain a UserControl page name InfoForm.ascx.

InfoForm.ascx have some textboX to let user key in value.

But, after I key in those value, and click on a button in SearchGift.ascx, InfoForm.ascx seen post back and those value gone. Thus, I cant get any value that I key in early.

I also not sure which part of code I should post here. Hopefully my sentences here can describe my problem clearly.

Kindly Let me know if my question is not clear.

Regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

earlier i solved my problem using this article

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3684/Retaining-State-for-Dynamically-Created-Controls-i

try this also

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/35360/ViewState-in-Dynamic-Control

I've had the same problem in the past. Another way is give the dynamically-added control an ID, and made sure it retained that same ID also on postback (in my case, I kept all the information in the session, and re-created the controls).

Once the postbacked control has the same ID as as before, Microsoft did magic and refilled the controls with the pre-postback values.

Comment: Thanks. But I not really understand on the second article. What does the capital letter [VIEWSTATEKEY] meanings? I type in my place, get red line error. --> Does not exist in the current context.

Comment: type it like this - Viewstate["viewstatekey"] = any value;

Comment: it is like adding a variable to viewstate. you can read it from here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31344/Beginner-s-Guide-To-View-State